# Showing only features related to selected feature in another layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, expression, filter, select

**I have:** ways (tracks) and points (way signs). The tracks are outgoing from the way signs.

**This should be the visible result:**
The ways with the name 'A' are visible (coloured) because the related way sign 'A' is selected. This is the result I'm looking for:

[image: GIS]

**The question is:** How do I **show or highlight** only the tracks, related to the selected way sign?

**What I did:**
With this rule in styling settings, I can realize the wanted result with one layer (waysigs OR tracks): I select the way sign /tracks and it becomes red because I defined it as a styling rule.

[image][image]

Then I tried this for the tracks (without understanding, what I'm doing) related to the example syntax in the expression builder Help section¹:

```
    is_selected(get_feature('waysigns', 'fid', "name"), 'waysigns')
```

but without the expected result...

---

> ¹
> s_selected(get_feature('streets', 'name', "street_name"), 'streets')
> → True if the current building's street is selected.

---

**Why do I need this:** In my project I have thousands of tracks and some way signs. A lot of the tracks are crossing each other and it is impossible, to see, which track comes from which way sign. To have a better overview, of which tracks are related to which way sign, I simply would like to select the way sign and get its related tracks.

Comment: where's the question ?

Comment: What do you mean by "related"? Having same attribute value or intersecting each other? I guess the latter.

Comment: both: They have the same attribute (name) and intersecting each other.

Comment: For reference, here you have another option (also mentions 2 plugins that might help you): [Visualize polyline/linestring n-to-n relations in QGIS as part of Python Plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382713/visualize-polyline-linestring-n-to-n-relations-in-qgis-as-part-of-python-plugin/382833#382833)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1: Flashing the related features

Run this script in QGIS Python Editor. I couldn't solve how to disable flashing when another point was selected.

```py
w_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("way_signs")[0]
t_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("tracts")[0]
f1, f2 = 'fid', 'name'
flashes, duration = 3, 3000 # 3 times, 3 second

def highlight(ids):
    if len(ids)==0:
        return
        
    w = w_lyr.getFeature(ids[0])
    r = f2 + " = '" + str(w[f1]) + "'" #r: request
    
    t_ids = [t.id() for t in t_lyr.getFeatures(r) 
                        if w[f1]==t[f2] and t.geometry().intersects(w.geometry())]
    
    iface.mapCanvas().flashFeatureIds(t_lyr, t_ids,
                                      flashes=flashes,
                                      duration=duration)

w_lyr.selectionChanged.connect(highlight)
```

[image]

Before you run the script again, be sure you disconnected the function using:

```py
w_lyr.selectionChanged.disconnect(highlight)
```

---

### Solution 2: Selecting the related features

Using a custom function, you can solve the issue. Add the next script as a new function in the "Function Editor" tab.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesgeometry=True)
def select_related(point_layer_name, field1, field2, feature, parent):
    point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(point_layer_name)[0]
    point = point_layer.selectedFeatures()[0]
    if point[field1]== feature[field2] and feature.geometry().intersects(point.geometry()):
        return True
```

Click "Save and Load Functions". Then, in the "Expression" tab, enter this line:

```py
select_related('way_signs', 'fid', 'name')
```

[image]

There must be a solution which uses only built-in functions, but I didn't figure it out.

---

### Solution 3: would be creating a temporary layer containing the related features.

---

### Solution 4: would be somehow styling the related features by means of the "Layer Styling" panel like you try to do.

Comment: Great! But I don't need a selection. I simply want the related features "highlighted" in another color/style. I'll update my question to this...

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using a virtual field on the point layer, and a virtual layer.

1. Add a virtual field to the point layer, of type `integer size 1` and populate it using the expression `is_selected()`

(note: don't use a `boolean` type because of this [bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31798).)

`[image]

So when a point is selected, the value in this field will be set to 1.

2. Create a virtual layer that will join the point layer to the line layer base on their geometry intersection. Then filter out the points to keep only the selected one.

At last, style this virtual layer as you wish.

When you select a point, you will have to pan the map a bit to refresh the virtual layer.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name for yours

```sql
select l.*
from lines l 
  join points p 
    on st_intersects(p.geometry,l.geometry)
where  p.selected = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Conceptually this seemed like a nice idea to me, but in practice I find that it is very slow (working on a table with about 10 million records). Pity

Comment: @KoenVer for larger datasets, I would put the data in a database - with proper spatial indexes -  and create a view that does the join between the point/line layers. Then in QGIS the virtual layer would be used only to filter the view using the selected ID

Comment: Just to make myself clear: sorry for editing/improving your answer. Please do not consider it rude

Comment: Sorry, but I will disagree with you. (1) Regarding the indentation the reader needs to see where chapter 1 ends and chapter 2 starts, in the case of a numbered list it should follow the same logic. Everything that belongs to point 1 should be inside of it etc. (2) IMHO using links helps to promote the QGIS Documentation, as well as referring to vital sections i.e. *virtual field* and *virtual layer* However, I will be more critical about myself to avoid these contrary effects. For now, this is just my style ^_^