# Visualize polyline n-to-n relations in QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, spatial-relationship

I have 2 traffic networks (A and B) with links relating to each other. Each link has an id. E.g. link 1 of network A can have a relation to 3 links of network B. Link 2 of network A might also have a relation to 1 of those 3 links of network B, and also to another one etc. I'm depicting these relations in GeoJSONs with features in the form of:

```
  "features": [{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "Street with a certain name",
    "relations": [
      123,
      456,
      789
    ]
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [-74.06, 40.60],
      [-74.06, 40.60],
      [-74.06, 40.61]
    ]
  }
}]
```

So in a different layer/GeoJSON of network B there will be linestrings with the IDs 123, 456, 789 that relate to the `Linestring` above of network A and vice versa.

Another possibility, instead of storing relations within the JSON, would be to have the relations in a separate (csv) table, with each row depicting a relation, like:

```
id_A,id_B
12345,123
12345,456
12345,789
etc.
```

I would like to be able to visualize these relations, e.g. when selecting the link of network A above, I would like the 3 related  links of network B to be 'highlighted' in some way, or at least be filtered automatically.

Is there a way to easily and efficiently achieve this in QGIS, maybe via a Python script (Networks could contain multiple thousand links)? This is supposed to be part of a larger Python plugin. My preferred way to achieve this would either be highlighting the relating links while at the same time keeping a view of both whole networks, either somehow automatically when this 'mode' is enabled, or at least by activating some script after selecting the link, like 'Visualize Relations'.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/364117/29431) gives you a hint. When a point is selected, the related lines are highlighted

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format. We're a little different from other sites. For questions that involve code, we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a code snippet in your question.

Comment: Thanks! flashFeatures seems to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are loading these 2 layers to QGIS and creating a QGIS relation among them.

So, there are at least 2 plugins that help you select child features when you select a parent feature. These plugins are [Actions for relations](https://pigrecoinfinito.com/2020/12/08/qgis-relazioni-plugin-actions-for-relations/) and [Select by relationship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGfFCOfAS5E&feature=youtu.be). Follow the links to see how they work.

Besides these two plugins (none of them actually highlighted child features as I wanted on QGIS 3.16.1), you also have the following code snippet (adapted [from the latter plugin](https://github.com/pyarchinit/selectbyrelationship_repo/blob/master/select_by_relationship_handler.py#L201) I mentioned) to test parent-child visualization:

```
parent = iface.activeLayer()  # Get parent layer from the ToC 

def selectChildren(fids, foo, bar):
    relations = QgsProject.instance().relationManager().relationsByName('my_rel')
    rel = relations[0]  # Assuming we only have 1 relation named 'my_rel'
    referencingLayer = rel.referencingLayer()
    referencedLayer = rel.referencedLayer()

    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(fids)
    fit = referencedLayer.getFeatures(request)
    childIds = []
    for f in fit:
        it = rel.getRelatedFeatures(f)
        childIds.extend([i.id() for i in it])

    iface.mapCanvas().flashFeatureIds(referencingLayer, childIds)

parent.selectionChanged.connect(selectChildren)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

---

*Note that the code snippet relies on the explicit QGIS relation set between both layers, instead of discovering spatial relations on the fly.*